# Where does sudo apt -y install dotnet6 install .NET 6?

Tags: .net, ubuntu

I installed .NET 6 on my ubuntu machine version 22.10 using the snap package manager. I'm wanting to create a web api core project using aspnetcore, but was having issues with linux asp.net core segmentation fault (core dumped) errors so I removed the snap version and installed it using sudo apt-get install -y aspnetcore-runtime-6.0.

However now when I run dotnet --info I get bash: /snap/bin/dotnet: No such file or directory. There is a dotnet directory inside /etc, but it only shows two files: install_location_x64 and install_location. Is there a step I'm missing? Or is a reliable way to install .NET 6, specifically the aspnetcore runtime and sdk so I can build the web api project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple [search](https://packages.ubuntu.com/kinetic/aspnetcore-runtime-6.0) tells me, that the package `aspnetcore-runtime-6.0` [only have many `.dll`s of ASP .NET Core under `/usr/lib/dotnet/dotnet6-6.0.110/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App/6.0.10/`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/kinetic/amd64/aspnetcore-runtime-6.0/filelist).

But it has a transitive on [`dotnet-host`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/kinetic/dotnet-host), which [has an executable called `dotnet` under `/usr/lib/dotnet/dotnet6-6.0.110/`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/kinetic/amd64/dotnet-host/filelist), and, `/usr/lib/dotnet/dotnet`, if you [download the package and dive into it](http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/d/dotnet6/dotnet-host_6.0.113-0ubuntu1%7E22.10.1_amd64.deb).

So, you may find the `dotnet` executable there.

---

For the `bash: /snap/bin/dotnet: No such file or directory` thing, you may check your `$PATH` environment variable first.

Answer (score 2):

Every time I encounter problem packages for a particular OS, I just check their official docs. Found this [handy manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-ubuntu#2210) that details out the steps

Seems like it's also recommended to [remove preview and/or previous versions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/remove-runtime-sdk-versions?pivots=os-linux) before a fresh install

```
sudo apt remove dotnet6
```

Then get the packages,

```
wget https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/22.10/packages-microsoft-prod.deb -O packages-microsoft-prod.deb
sudo dpkg -i packages-microsoft-prod.deb
rm packages-microsoft-prod.deb
```

Install the SDK and runtime,

```
sudo apt-get install -y dotnet-sdk-6.0
sudo apt-get install -y dotnet-runtime-6.0
```

These are just steps from the manual above and I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

After downloading the package, during installation, you can see the installation path in the terminal
May be try check directory: `/usr/bin`